# How to get missing co-ordinates on mousemove javascript

Tags: javascript

If I move mouse quickly some of the pixels are missing, if you check my console output below you will see the difference.

```
(index):325 new y -  131
(index):326 old x -  462
(index):327 old y -  103
(index):324 new x -  484
(index):325 new y -  161
(index):326 old x -  474
(index):327 old y -  131
(index):324 new x -  498
(index):325 new y -  229
(index):326 old x -  484
```

at one point e.clientX is 462 and it suddenly went to 484 and then 474.

I need the missing pixels for my calculations.

Comment: You can't, the data is not stored, and the exact route of the mouse is unknown. You could interpolate the "missing pixels" assuming a stright line between the old and new pixel (or create a more complex formula based on the last stored values), but it's only an approximation.

Comment: @Teemu its not guaranteed user would move mouse in a straight line.

Comment: Yep, as I said, "_the exact route of the mouse is unknown_". Interpolation means, that you calculate a straight line between two closest known points, that'll give you a good approximation of the real route. If you're not handling this in a mousemove handler, you could take more points (4 - 5), create a formula (bezier?) based on the coordinates, and calculate the position for all points between the 1st and 5th point. Then repeat with the next 5 points etc. This will be a time-consuming operation, hence the data can't be handled within the mousemove handler.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a pen stroke, @ OP?

Comment: @GetSet I am rotating a div and restricting rotation so the div's corners wont go out of its parent. It should only rotate until the div corner meet its parent.

Comment: But you already got answers for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62442929/1169519) ..? If you want to change the angle with mouse, only you need is the angle between the current position and the origin of the rotation, then just limit the rotation angle to the maximum. You don't need to check every pixel for this.

Comment: @Teemu I am almost done. just this mousemove accuracy, the divs rotation stop slightly before it touch its parent due to this inaccuracy.

Comment: The angle of the mouse position related to the origin is easy to calculate: `Math.atan2(y - b, x - a)`, where x, y are mouse coordinates, and a, b are the coordinates of the rotation origin. Tracing exact pixels of mousemove for this is impossible, just compare angles instead.

Comment: @Teemu its pretty complicated the whole scenario , I will make a fiddle if I dont get a way out of it.

Comment: Maybe that's better to ask in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The browser can only get that information every time the event fires, which is every frame. NOT every pixel. It can't capture every point in between. The closest you can get is to check the time from the last one and the time now, and try to guess where it was in between frames. `getTime()` returns the milliseconds. If you take that minus the last `getTime()` you will know how long the event took to fire (this depends on the speed of the user's browser, other background processes, etc ... events do not fire perfectly). So from that you can figure out where the mouse was at some point in between the events.

Think of what happens when your laptop is running out of batteries... or on a phone where people just touch the screen and the "mouse" cursor jumps... and you will see the problem. It is impossible to capture every tiny change.

*Edit* as noted in the comment, you would not know the actual position between those frames, only the position if the user moved the mouse in a straight line.