# How does getBoundingClientRect() calculate x and y position after the element is rotated?

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

I have this initial box with height of 200px and width of 300px where it is placed 150px to the top and 150px to the left. This is what `getBoundingClientRect()` gives:

`DOMRect {x: 150, y: 150, width: 300, height: 200, top: 150, …}`

```js
console.log(box.getBoundingClientRect())
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 150px;"></div>
```

Now, when I rotate the box to 45deg, then it gives me the following result:

`DOMRect {x: 123.22330474853516, y: 73.22330474853516, width: 353.55340576171875, height: 353.55340576171875, top: 73.22330474853516, …}`

```js
console.log(box.getBoundingClientRect())
```

```html
<div id="box" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 150px; transform: rotate(45deg)"></div>
```

As you can see, `getBoundingClientRect()` returns different result when the box is rotated. I just wanted to know the math behind this calculation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Draw two (imaginary) vertical lines that touch either side of the rotated element, draw two horizontal lines that touch top and bottom … that’s the new _bounding rectangle_

Comment: [See a rotated element and the box](https://jsfiddle.net/pqtj87o1/). You can play with the CSS of `.rot` element to see how it effects on the box, ex. add a padding or margin to the rotated element.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62444008/1169519) is some math you can apply to calculate the box if needed.

Comment: Did you solve it?